# Convert a for loop to a do-while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I saw a way to calculate the product of odd numbers from 1 to 15 using a for loop on here a few days ago:

```
int product = 1;        

for(int count = 1; count <= 15; count++){
    if (count % 2 != 0)
        product = product * count;
}
```

Is it possible to convert it into a do-while loop?

Comment: **Any** `while` loop can be rewritten as `for` loop and visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
int product = 1;
int count = 1;
do {
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
        product *= count;
    }
    count++;
} while (count <= 15)
```

More generally, every for-loop can be converted in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

```
int product = 1;
int count = 1; // first part of the for loop
do {
    if (count % 2 != 0)
        product = product * count; // assuming product as been defined
    count++; // third part of the for loop
} while (count <= 15); // second part of the for loop
```

As a matter of fact you can also write it as a `while` loop too.

```
int product = 1;
int count = 1;
while(count <= 15)
{
    if (count % 2 != 0)
        product = product * count; // assuming product as been defined
    count++;
}
```